# React: weird closure bug caused by setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where there is a counter and a button to increment it. After the counter reaches to `5` we cannot increment it further. And there is a checkbox as well, when checked, the counter will increment by 1 every second.

The code is fairly straightforward

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isActivated, setIsActivated] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    console.log("count inner", count);
    if (count < 5) {
      setCount((c) => c + 1);
    }
  };

  const timerRef = useRef(null);
  console.log("count outer", count);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActivated) {
      timerRef.current = setInterval(incrementCount, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    }
  }, [isActivated]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={(e) => {
          setIsActivated(e.target.checked);
        }}
      />
      <label>activate internal</label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, it has a bug: after you checked the checkbox, the counter will not stop at `5`. Instead, it will keep incrementing. By putting `console.log` inside of `incrementCount` I found that the `count` state always stays at `1`. I feel like it is a **stale closure** problem. But I cannot really pinpoint what exactly it is that is causing the problem.

Here is a live demo you can play with https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kepler-dedb6?file=/src/App.js

By the way, I know that I should have wrapped `incrementCount` inside of `useCallback` to make it stay referentially the same between renders. But that still doesn't answer the question that why is that the `count` variable in `incrementCount` is stale.

Comment: Great job with the codesandbox sample. You never deactivated the timer after 5 seconds.

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping `incrementCount` in a `useCallback` and making `count` a dependency. Then include `incrementCount` in the dependencies of `useEffect`. Also, you need to return a function in useEffect that clears the interval. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-volhard-uur5e

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ You code will create a new instance of setInterval for each increment. I believe it will cause a memory leak.

Comment: @SILENT The interval gets cleared in case any of the dependencies of the `useEffect` change. So, I believe it wouldn't cause a memory leak. Unless I'm missing something else. I understand for this specific use-case, this is not the most straightforward code. I simply made the change to pinpoint the cause of counter not stopping at 5.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Ah, so on each refresh the useEffect's return is also run? Learn something new every day!

Comment: @SILENT Yes. The return value of the function inside a `useEffect` is a cleanup function that gets executed in case a dependency changes and the effect is called again. More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `incrementCount`, you are not just using the state closure to update the state. You are also reading straight from the `count` variable (`if (count < 5)`) which always has the stale value, unless you redefine the function on every re-render (which you do) and you use the re-defined function in `setInterval` which you don't.

Once `incrementCount` is run once, your component gets rerendered and you'll have a new instance of `count`, and also a new definition of `incrementCount` which is bound to the new `count`, but your previous definition of `incrementCount` bound to stale `count` is still in the memory and is being executed because of `setInterval`.

You can:

- make the `count` also a `ref`
- use `useCallback` for `incrementCount` and include it in the `useEffect` depdendencies. Also, provide a cleanup for `setInterval` in `useEffect`.
- move the conditional `if (count < 5)` inside the state closure, so you wouldn't rely on stale context. `setCount((c) => (c < 5 ? c + 1 : c));`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I feel like this is the only answer that directly addresses why `count` is stale in `incrementCount`. Thank you! Btw could you make an example of how I can work around this issue by making a `ref` for `count`?

Comment: @Joji Happy to help. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-resonance-9zgyc?file=/src/App.js:0-1130) is an example of your code with a ref for the count.
After writing it, it doesn't seem such a good idea tho.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `useEffect` re-runs when its dependencies get changed.

In your code, your effect runs only if `isActivate` change, and it will get the function incrementCount once with the context (count = 1)

**1st way: set count based on previous state**

Try to change your incrementCount like this:

```
  const incrementCount = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("count inner", count);
    setCount((prevCount) => (prevCount < 5 ? prevCount + 1 : prevCount));
  }, [count]);
```

This way works, but your incrementCount still runs every 1 second which is not necessary.

**2nd way, use setTimeout instead of setInterval**

So, instead of use Interval, you can use `setTimeout` that runs every 1 second, and update your count.

When your count state get changed => your effect get changed => set Time out 1 second again.

Like below:

```
  const [isActivated, setIsActivated] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const incrementCount = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  }, []);

  const timerRef = useRef(null);
  console.log("count outer", count);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActivated && count < 5) {
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(incrementCount, 1000);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    }
  }, [isActivated, incrementCount, count]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-violet-q7r9j?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I know you were not asking for help to rewrite your code to fix the weird behavior. Rather you were simply interested to find out WHY it behaved the way that it did. And I do see the answers so far have supplied superb explanation. But I just couldn't help myself thinking that what you're doing can be accomplished so much easier and so much cleaner with `useReducer`. More concise code, no unnecessary re-renders, and, most importantly, it works precisely as intended. So I am just posting it here for anybody who may be interested ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-monad-4pfpf?file=/src/App.js)):

```
const max = 5;

export default function App() {
  const [isActivated, setIsActivated] = useState(false);

  const [count, increment] = useReducer(state => state < max ? state + 1 : state, 1);

  const timerRef = useRef(null);
  console.log("count outer", count);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActivated) {
      timerRef.current = setInterval(increment, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    }
  }, [isActivated]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={(e) => {
          setIsActivated(e.target.checked);
        }}
      />
      <label>activate internal</label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) is usually an excellent choice when you need to update a state variable based on what that variable is current set to. The offial docs put it best:

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

Counter apps like yours are a perfect example. Hence, the decision to use it instead of `useState` was a no-brainier.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. Could you expound on why `useReducer` is better than `useState` here? I mean I can tell it is indeed cleaner. But I wonder how you were able to make that judgment to use one over the other?

Comment: @Joji I have updated my answer to provide some backing for the logic behind the judgement I made.